# Navbar overlay in Framework7

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, navbar, html-framework-7

I'm using `Framework7` to create an application for Android and iOS, but I have a problem:

When I switch from one page to another, the `navbar` section of the page from which I make the call does not go away, and then the second page is overlay creating a bad effect.

I added the `view` and I initialized the `dynamicNavbar` parameter with the following syntax:

`var Myview = myApp.addView("#myIdView");`

This is my code:

**index.html**

```
<div class="views tabs toolbar-fixed theme-amber">

    <div id="my_list" class="view tab active">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="center">My App Name</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pages navbar-fixed">
            <div data-page="my_list" class="page">
                <div class="page-content index">
                    <div class="content-block">
                        <a href="pages/my_new_page.html">
                            <div class="my_item">
                                <div class="left_content">
                                    here my content
                                </div>
                                <div class="right_content ti-angle-right">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**my_new_page.html**

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="index.html" class="ti-angle-left col_212121 back custom"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            My new navbar title
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pages navbar-fixed">
    <div data-page="my_page" class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
            my new content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**my-app.js**

```
// Initialize app
var myApp= new Framework7();

// If we need to use custom DOM library, let's save it to $$ variable:
var $$ = Dom7;

// Add view
var Myview = myApp.addView("#my_list", {
    dynamicNavbar: true
});
```

In the attached screenshot of what happens.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you read the framework7 documentation carefully on the section of Dynamic Navbar you will notice it starts with these exact words:

> Dynamic Navbar is supported only in iOS Theme
>
> One of the iOS awesome features is the dynamic navigation bar
>   (navbar). Navbar's elements will slide and fade during pages
>   transition and swipe back when dynamic navbar is enabled.
>
> **It works only with Through-type layout**
>
> It should be enabled during View initialization by passing
>   dynamicNavbar: true parameter

In your html code you use the `navbar-fixed` class which cannot coexist with the dynamic Navbar. To give you an example, the html code of "my_new_page.html" should be changed from: `<div class="pages navbar-fixed">` to `<div class="pages navbar-through">`. The same modification should be made to your "index.html" code also.

If you want to read more about dynamic navbar in framework7 here is the link: [Framework7 dynamic navbar](http://framework7.io/docs/dynamic-navbar.html).

**Edit:** I also noticed that you have a statement `var Myview = myApp.addView("#myIdView");`. In your HTML I can't see an HTML element with its id set to "myIdView" so I can't see where you want this to be declared.

A set of more changes you should probably make:

In your index.html page try this change: `<div id="my_list" class="view-main tab active">` and then go to your js file and modify it exactly like this:

```
// Initialize app
var myApp= new Framework7();

// If we need to use custom DOM library, let's save it to $$ variable:
var $$ = Dom7;

// Add view
var Myview = myApp.addView(".view-main", {
    dynamicNavbar: true
});
```

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for the reply.
I already use iOS theme (also on Android), I have already initialized the view with the parameter `dynamicNavbar: true`, but also by like you told me using `navbar-through` class the problem persists

Comment: You are welcome. Give me a few minutes and I will edit my answer adding some more things I noticed with a clear head today.